# Want to scatter plot with duplicate values of x with lower values to be less highlighted

Tags: python, visualization

[This is the sturcture of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUs1T.png). I hope you guys can help me!

If any one has any idea how to do that in any data visualization library in python please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use several library such Matplotlib, Seaborn and Plotly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).